# SQL Server stored procedure always returning 0

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was asked to calculate a percentage of a number through a stored procedure in SQL Server, but for some reason no matter what the parameters are, I always get a 0.

My question is what is happening here?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE pCalcular
    @PrecioTotal INT,
    @cantidad INT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT ' Calculando ' + CAST (@PrecioTotal * @cantidad AS VARCHAR(40))
    SELECT @cantidad = @PrecioTotal * @cantidad
END
```

I'm calling the procedure the following way, I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
DECLARE @abc AS INT
EXEC @abc = pCalcular 70, .1
PRINT @abc
```

Comment: The 0 is just the return code of the proc. 0 means it was executed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only setting the value @cantidad in the procedure. You just need to SELECT that value from the PROC. Try just having;

```
SELECT @PrecioTotal * @cantidad
```

Also, take a look at [other ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) of returning data from procedures like `OUTPUT` parameters.

**EDIT:**

Your procedure should look like this;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE pCalcular
    @PrecioTotal INT,
    @cantidad INT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT ' Calculando ' + CAST (@PrecioTotal * @cantidad AS VARCHAR(40))
    SELECT @PrecioTotal * @cantidad
END
```

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE pCalcularIva 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 (@total INT,@porcentaje INT, @result INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT @result = @total * @porcentaje
 SELECT @result
END
GO`

Comment: Woops, didnt finish writing my comment, I am sorry about that. How about something like this? In this case, I tested it and it still returned a 0.

Comment: No. In this case, you don't need to select into a variable. You just the result of your select to be the data set returned from the procedure. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, got the value I wanted!